# Como formatar o resultado do sum() no dataframe em Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum

Gostaria de formatar o resultado do `sum()`.

Quando uso o seguinte comando:

```
# Valor concedido de aposentadoria por ano
df.groupby('Ano')['Vlr Benefícios Concedidos (R$)'].sum()
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
Ano
1996 --- 1.646539e+08
1997 --- 2.360492e+08
1998 --- 1.730143e+08
1999 --- 8.525424e+07
2000 --- 7.506213e+07
```

Gostaria de formatar esses números para que fiquem por exemplo `1.646.539,00`.

Comment: O que seria df? dataframe? Apesar de ter resposta aceita, a pergunta está incompleta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes formatar a coluna usando o método `apply`:

```
df.groupby('Ano')['Vlr Benefícios Concedidos (R$)'].sum().apply(lambda x: "{:,.2f}".format(x))
```

Que mostra o seguinte formato: `1,646,539.00`

Para teres os pontos como separador de milhares (`1.646.539,00`) é preciso alterar um pouco para algo como:

```
df.groupby('Ano')['Vlr Benefícios Concedidos (R$)'].sum().apply(lambda x: "{:_.2f}".format(x).replace('.', ',').replace('_', '.'))
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

## Importar o módulo `localize`

Para não ter que **usar `apply.lambda` em todo lugar** você pode usar o módulo padrão `import localize` que formata números e datas para o idioma local, neste caso `pt_BR.UTF8` para o Brasil ([ver documentacao](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.10/library/locale.html#module-locale)).

Usar a função `localize.setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.UTF-8")` para modificar todos atributos: datas, nomes do mês, dias da semana e valores numéricos para formato português do Brasil.

## Criar uma função formatadora

A verdadeira solução está em criar uma **função formatadora** que passe o valor para ser convertido usando `localize.currency(val, symbol=True. grouping=False, international=False)` e associá-la como *default* de formatação do pandas.

### Função localize.currency

As opções de **currency** são:

- `symbol`, se *True* mostra o símbolo que representa a moeda, neste caso R$.
- `grouping`, se True formata usando separador de milhar ex: 1.234,56
- `international`, se True usa o símbolo internacional da moeda. (Real Brasileiro é BRL)).

### Função formatadora

```py
def num_formatter(valor):
  return lc.currency(valor, symbol=False, grouping=True)
```

### Opção do pandas default de formatação

Associá-la à opção *default* de formatação floats com pd.set_option('display.float_format', num_formatter)`-- assume`import pandas as pd`.

## Código completo

```py
import pandas as pd
import localize

localize.set_locale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8")

def num_formatter(valor):
  return lc.currency(valor, symbol=False, grouping=True, international=False)

pd.set_option('display.float_format', num_formatter)
```